# Why is the error `Celluloid::Condition signaled spuriously` caused in Celluloid?

Tags: ruby, asynchronous, celluloid

I'm trying to wait on a condition of an async code, here's the snippet:

```
condition = Celluloid::Condition.new   
Rails.logger.debug "Sending RPC request to #{subject}"
NATS.start uri: ENV['NATS_SERVER'] do 
  Rails.logger.debug "Connected to #{ENV['NATS_SERVER']}"
  sid = NATS.request(subject,msg) do |response|
    Rails.logger.debug "Assigning response"
    condition.signal response
    NATS.stop
  end
  NATS.timeout(sid, 1) do
    NATS.stop
    condition.signal ASYNC_ERROR
    raise "One second timeout waiting for a NATS RPC reply from #{subject}"
  end
end

result = condition.wait
if result = ASYNC_ERROR
  raise "Error in RPC call"
else
  return result
end
```

I get the exception `Celluloid::Condition signaled spuriously` but there's no extra information and I don't really understand why is it caused and https://github.com/celluloid/celluloid/wiki/Conditions doesn't provide more information.

Why is this caused and how can I fix it?

Comment: No experience with `Celluloid` but here is the [source](https://github.com/celluloid/celluloid/blob/master/lib/celluloid/condition.rb#L67) seems like there are no waiters in `@waiters` causing `if waiter = @waiters.shift` to be nil and thus the error is raised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And to answer your question exactly like your stated question, using a condition.

### Within the scope of an actor:

```
class Nats
  include Celluloid

  def initialize
    @condition = Celluloid::Condition.new
  end

  def start
    Rails.logger.debug "Sending RPC request to #{subject}"
    NATS.start uri: ENV['NATS_SERVER'] do 
      Rails.logger.debug "Connected to #{ENV['NATS_SERVER']}"
      sid = NATS.request(subject,msg) do |response|
        Rails.logger.debug "Assigning response"
        @condition.signal response
        NATS.stop
      end
      NATS.timeout(sid, 1) do
        NATS.stop
        @condition.signal ASYNC_ERROR
        raise "One second timeout waiting for a NATS RPC reply from #{subject}"
      end
    end
  end

  def value
    @condition.wait
  end
end

nats = Nats.new
nats.async.start

result = nats.value
if result = ASYNC_ERROR
  raise "Error in RPC call"
else
  return result
end
```

---

This is even less tested, but ought to show you the basic approach if you aren't going to use a `Future` like my other answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your condition is not operating in the context of an actor. Notice in the example, an actor is used. It is possible to avoid using an actor context but that is very different, and at the root of the error you receive.

If you would not like to implement this in an actor, as in the example, here is an approach you can implement without an actor:

### Use `Celluloid::Future` ( even if nested `async` calls are inside )

```
nats = Celluloid::Future.new {
    blocker = Queue.new
    Rails.logger.debug "Sending RPC request to #{subject}"
    NATS.start uri: ENV['NATS_SERVER'] do 
        Rails.logger.debug "Connected to #{ENV['NATS_SERVER']}"
        sid = NATS.request(subject,msg) do |response|
            Rails.logger.debug "Assigning response"
            NATS.stop
            blocker << response
        end
        NATS.timeout(sid, 1) do
            NATS.stop
            blocker << nil
            #de "One second timeout waiting for a NATS RPC reply from #{subject}"
        end
    end
    blocker.pop || raise ASYNC_ERROR
}

begin
    result = nats.value
rescue ASYNC_ERROR
    raise "Error in RPC call"
rescue => ex
    #de Other exception
else
    return result
end
```

---

The above is a loose example for implementing `async` response gathering, with exception handling. That is one example among many possible approaches.

Comment: In this case, wouldn't `nats.value` simply be nil? I don't see how the execution would stop until the assignment of `responding = response`.

Comment: If `NATS.request` is asynchronous, yes, `responding` will always be `nil` ... otherwise, it'd work. If it is asynchronous, I can see why you're looking to use a `Condition`

Comment: Exactly, it's async, hence the use of the condition. I'll try the future and let you know if it works.

Comment: I don't imagine it will. You could use a `Queue` though, to cause the `Future` to wait for the inner async call to complete.

Comment: There I mocked up using a `Queue`